# MCU not turning on via high side PMOS or PNP BJT

Tags: transistors, opto-isolator, rectifier, attiny

This board basically senses 24 VAC and drives a relay using the attiny10 as delay timer (already tried 555).
The board will only be driving a few LEDs < 12 mA and a 5 V relay with ~40 mA coil current.

I've built a prototype circuit on breadboard using the schematic in pic. But the PMOS or PNP used to turn on the MCU (ATTINY10) seem to be partially saturated when off. With Q3, I checked the voltage. While the optocoupler was off, it was at about 2.3 V at drain. LED2 is also ON but very faint. When 24 VAC is sensed, LED2 goes full brightness and there is about 4.9 V at the Q3 drain but the MCU doesn't turn on.

The MCU works as expected when connected to the 5 V output from buck directly but not from the transistor switches.

The PMOS is DMP3050LVT, VgsTH = -2 V

Any ideas? Problem with rectification?

[image]

Comment: Update: corrected q3 as Rohat noted, and connect a 10k across collector and ground. Still nothing. I tried a full wave rectifier instead and everything works as expected, so the problem is with the rectification?

Comment: C4 in the circuit is absurd, remove it. Connection between pin 1 and pin 6 of U2 is absurd, place 100nF between them. R4 and R3 are interchanged. HEAT is not a DC signal, it is a square wave with mains frequency booting the tiny 50 or 60 times per second

Comment: @Jens, thanks for the tips. If there are 2 back to back led's driving the base of U15. The output should be steady, no?

Comment: That would be nice, but no, one of them is just a normal diode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extension to the answer from @Rohat Kılıç

HEAT is not a DC signal, it is a square wave with mains frequency booting the tiny 50 or 60 times per second. A capacitor of 22 µF minimum parallel to R7 is required to keep Q3 conducting during one half wave.

Answer (score 1):

Q3's placement is wrong. Correct placements is shown below (find the difference):

[image]

Plus, I suggest you to place a 5k or 10k across the Q3's collector and ground (collector load).